# Spoon PDI Data Validator Error

Tags: etl, kettle, spoon, pdi

I am trying to validate that an assignment is correct. I can't say much, however we have internal and external users. I have an SQL Script that looks for anything other than internal on an internal assignment - result should be 0 rows. I then place this in a SQL table. After that, I've got a statement to calculate if there is an assignment error, and then I store that in a variable. Based off this, I try to validate the data with the 'Data Validator' step. Running the code manually, it should pass, however Spoon PDI is giving me the following error:

```
2015/05/04 13:03:19 - Data Validator.0 - ERROR (version 5.2.0.0, build 1 from 2014-09-30_19-48-28 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2015/05/04 13:03:19 - Data Validator.0 - ERROR (version 5.2.0.0, build 1 from 2014-09-30_19-48-28 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
2015/05/04 13:03:19 - Data Validator.0 - Correct Group/Dashboard Assignment
2015/05/04 13:03:19 - Data Validator.0 - Correct Group/Dashboard Assignment
2015/05/04 13:03:19 - Data Validator.0 - 
2015/05/04 13:03:19 - Data Validator.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.validator.Validator.processRow(Validator.java:159)
2015/05/04 13:03:19 - Data Validator.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2015/05/04 13:03:19 - Data Validator.0 -    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2015/05/04 13:03:19 - Data Validator.0 - Caused by: org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.validator.KettleValidatorException: Correct Group/Dashboard Assignment
2015/05/04 13:03:19 - Data Validator.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.validator.Validator.validateFields(Validator.java:258)
2015/05/04 13:03:19 - Data Validator.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.validator.Validator.processRow(Validator.java:130)
2015/05/04 13:03:19 - Data Validator.0 -    ... 2 more
2015/05/04 13:03:19 - Data Validator.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=0, U=0, E=1)
2015/05/04 13:03:19 - transformation_group_dashboard_validator - ERROR (version 5.2.0.0, build 1 from 2014-09-30_19-48-28 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2015/05/04 13:03:19 - Spoon - The transformation has finished!!
2015/05/04 13:03:19 - transformation_group_dashboard_validator - ERROR (version 5.2.0.0, build 1 from 2014-09-30_19-48-28 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2015/05/04 13:03:19 - transformation_group_dashboard_validator - ERROR (version 5.2.0.0, build 1 from 2014-09-30_19-48-28 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2015/05/04 13:03:19 - transformation_group_dashboard_validator - Transformation detected one or more steps with errors.
2015/05/04 13:03:19 - transformation_group_dashboard_validator - Transformation is killing the other steps!
```

Is there anyway I can try to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem by deleting my Data Validator step and re-adding afresh one. I've noticed this with Spoon PDI a lot - the end outcome can sometimes be unpredictable and an occasional refresh of step fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the validator is rejecting your input(s), and according to the line in the source code, it isn't handling errors so all you get is an exception. Try creating another step linked to that validator, then right-click on the validator and choose "Define error handling..." and set up some error-related fields that the step will fill in. Also you will want to double-click on the Data Validator step and make sure the "Report all errors" and "...concatenate all errors" checkboxes are selected. That will ensure each row gets a full list of any validation errors that may have occurred.

This often happens when the validation conditions are not set the way the user intended them to be, so rows are rejected when they "should be" selected :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I managed to fix my problem by deleting my Data Validator step and re-adding  afresh one. I've noticed this with Spoon PDI a lot - the end outcome can sometimes be unpredictable and an occasional refresh of step fixes the issue.